# How to run init and destroy method every time in Spring

Tags: java, spring, aop

I have a class, CustomerService, which is a [Spring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework) bean. How do I run init() before I call getCustomer() and cleanUp() after finishing calling getCustomer()?

```
public void init(){
    faultCode = "";
    faultString ="";
}

public void cleanUp(){
    faultCode = faultException.getFaultCode().toString();
    faultString = faultException.getFaultStringOrReason().toString();
}

@Override
public Customer getCustomer(String customerCode) {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You'd generally use Spring AOP for this, but that's big topic.  Have a read: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html

Comment: it's too complex for my case, any other suggestion?

Comment: Do you want to call your cleanUp specifically when your getCustomer method finishes executing or is it like a resource releasing method that you would call before collecting hte CustomerService bean?

Comment: it's a resoure assigning method.

Comment: I would say that this is a bad design... What are you going to do when multiple concurrent threads call getCustomer? You will run into concurrency issues thread x seeing data from thread y etc.

Comment: then is it possible to make it thread safe for this design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do does not seems rational to me.  Anyway, from my understanding, what you are trying to do is, when the method of your bean is invoked, you want to invoke some pre-call and post-call routines.  At least two choices, depending on your design:

1. If that bean is supposed to be serving one request for one instance, (i.e. You are not serving multiple invocations at the same time), then make your bean a prototype bean (or other scopes, if you know what to do).  Spring will create a new bean to serve your request (i.e. Whenever you are trying to get the bean from Spring app context, Spring app context will create a new instance for you).  However, it will not be as straight-forward to inject the bean as what you are doing now.  You may need a factory method or by using scoped proxy
2. If that bean is supposed to be instantiated once, and used to serve multiple concurrent request, AOP is almost your only other choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
<bean id="CustomerService" 
         class="examples.CustomerService" init-method="init" destroy-method="cleanUp" />
```

Comment: it run once only during initial